# IIS 8 rewrite automatically my url

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a web site in MVC 5 ASP.NET,my Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am using IIS8.  My website works through Htpps protocol with a SSL.

**The problem is when I write my url (https: //www.-------.com), it is automatically changed to (https: //www.------.com/S(3gawihvzzjkgbw5nu3d3awo3)/ .**

Most of the times it works, but when I try to edit some data from my database (using SQL Server 2012), it does not work and it is redirected to the same page with the strange string changed (before *S(3gawihvzzjkgbw5nu3d3awo3)*, after *S(1eijnhnx13jbbxk1n4mrqwd2)* for example).

I have read from **http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module** that  the Software Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 does some changes like that, but I have looked for this program in my Server and I did not find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I made I mistake, The problem was not with the IIS, but with the MVC Project. 
I write what I've done if someone finds the same problem:

I had enabled the SSL in my project while I was trying some features like  Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on. So, I changed it to False and know it works perflectly!